# Invalid JSON primitive While parsing JSON in MVC Controller

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am creating a JSON string in my JavaScript and sending it to my controller in mvc application. My code which create JSON string :

```
     $('#btnassign').click(function () {

            var arrPrice = "";
            var arrMarkUP = "";

            $("table tr").each(function () {

                if ($(this).find('input:checkbox:first').is(':checked')) {

                    if ($(this).find('input.inputprice').val() != "") {
                        arrPrice += "{";
                        var price = $(this).find('input.inputprice').val();
                        var id = $(this).find('input[type=hidden]').val();
                        arrPrice += '"Id":"' + id + '","Price":"' + price + '"';
                        arrPrice += "},";
                    }
                    if ($(this).find('input.inputmarkup').val() != "") {
                        arrMarkUP += "{";
                        var price = $(this).find('input.inputmarkup').val();
                        var id = $(this).find('input[type=hidden]').val();
                        arrMarkUP += "Id:" + id + ",Price:" + price;
                        arrMarkUP += "},";
                    }
                }
            });

            var lastindexp = arrPrice.lastIndexOf(",");
            arrPrice = arrPrice.substring(0, lastindexp) + "|";
            var lastindexm = arrMarkUP.lastIndexOf(",");
            arrMarkUP = arrMarkUP.substring(0, lastindexm) + "|";
            alert(arrPrice);
            alert(arrMarkUP);

            $("#hdPrice").val(arrPrice);
            $("#hdMarkUP").val(arrMarkUP);

            $("#AssignProductForm").submit();
        });

    });
```

My JSON string generates from above code :

```
    {"Id":"1","Price":"4"},{"Id":"2","Price":"6"}
```

My Controller parsing code :

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddProducts(FormCollection collection, string txtsearch)
    {
        var ManualPricing = collection["hdPrice"].Split(new char[] { '|' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

         JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
         var Manual = ser.Deserialize<PriceMargin>(ManualPricing[0]);         
    }
```

Price margin is a class to which it should deserialize :

```
    public class PriceMargin
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Price { get; set; }
    }
```

Line `var Manual = ser.Deserialize<PriceMargin>(ManualPricing[0])` gives me an error:

> Invalid JSON primitive: {"Id":"2","Price":"9"}.

Solution:

```
var list = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<KeyValue>>(json);

public class KeyValue
{
   public string key;
   public string value;
}
```

Comment: Why are you manually building the string? You can use native datatypes and then encode those datatypes to JSON strong and decode the JSON string to native datatypes

Comment: i don't know how to do it , i am new to javascript , jquery !! any example ?

Comment: added example on using javascript objects

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON is invalid.

JSON can only have a single root object.

If you want to have multiple objects, serialize an array.

Answer (score 1):

To follow up the comment, if you want an array of objects to you could do something like:

```
pricesArray = [];
$("table tr").each(function () {
  if ($(this).find('input:checkbox:first').is(':checked')) {
    var price = $(this).find('input.inputprice').val();
    var id = $(this).find('input[type=hidden]').val();
    pricesArray.push({Id : id, Price: price});
  }
});
// pricesArray [{"Id":"1","Price":"4"},{"Id":"2","Price":"6"}]
```

`pricesArray` should now contain the data you want, it should be much easier to serialze and desearilze your data and send it around now

Answer (score 0):

Last time I encountered that error, I tried to pass an object value direct to the json data... i.e

```
data = { datavalue: @Object.valueField};
```

in Json

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Controller/FunctionToPostTo",
    data: data,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "html",
    success: function (response) {
        alert('Success');
    },
    failure: function (response) {
        alert('Failure');
        alert(response.responseText);
    },
    error: function (response) {
        alert('Error');
        alert(response.responseText);
    }
});
```

to solve the problem I created a separate variable and assigned the value to it,
passing the data value in Ajax I used the JSON.stringify function

```
var variableHolder = @Object.valueField;
data = { datavalue: variableHolder };
```

in Json

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Controller/FunctionToPostTo",
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "html",
    success: function (response) {
        alert('Success');
    },
    failure: function (response) {
        alert('Failure');
        alert(response.responseText);
    },
    error: function (response) {
        alert('Error');
        alert(response.responseText);
    }
});
```

Then the problem dissapeared